# ERROR: 8 - CURL error: GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received

Tags: php, curl, openssl, libcurl

I have infusionsoft api lib running on my server. In the code, I have to find contacts in infusionsoft using their method `dsFind`. If I use 5 as the limit to fetch no of contacts, it is working fine but when I make it more than 10, it is throwing below error:

`ERROR: 8 - CURL error: GnuTLS recv error (-9): A TLS packet with unexpected length was received`.

The same code is working fine on some other server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem relies on the fact that GnuTLS deals seriously with TLS protocol. [Nikos Mavrogiannopoulos explains this fact in a message on the gnutls-devel mailling list](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/gnutls-devel/2011-02/msg00002.html):

> Several sites terminate the TLS connection without following the TLS
>   protocol (i.e. sending closure alerts), but rather terminate the TCP
>   connection directly. This is a relic of SSLv2 and it seems other
>   implementations ignore this error. GnuTLS doesn't and thus prints
>   this error. You could ignore it, but then you could not distinguish
>   between a premature connection termination (i.e. by someone injecting
>   a stray TCP termination packet) and normal termination.